# CollectionView CurrentItem not sorting with the rest of the list

Tags: c#, wpf, uicollectionview

I have a `ListViewCollection` linked to an `ObservableCollection` that live sorts changes to the file size property of a folder item. (These items have `PropertyChanged` fired when needed.) The problem is, for some reason the `CurrentItem` that was last added to the list stays at the bottom of the list even when it's file size says otherwise. Every other item properly sorts to where it should be in the list as their size is refreshed.

I have no use for the `CurrentItem`, is there a way to enable sorting for it, or to disable the current item completely? All of the properties for it are read only and the methods to change the `CurrentItem` do not accept null as an option.

It seems that this issue is only triggered now after the `SortDescriptions` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the items in the list were arranged in ascending order, but when a new item was added it used to get added at the bottom of the list, rather than arranging in ascending order. My problem was it was clearing sorting after adding the new item.

I was using SortDescriptions.Clear(); after adding a new item.Removing that line solved my problem. Hope this helps!